# Android data binding lags when rendering

Tags: android, data-binding

I am using Android Data Binding with a `RecyclerView.Adapter`.
On `Adapter`'s `onCreateViewHolder` I call:

```
public TransfersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(
                ListItemMyDataBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        parent,
                        false));
}
```

So `ListItemMyDataBinding` is a representation of `list_item_my_data.xml`.

`Adapter`'s `onBindViewHolder` looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyData myData = mDataList.get(position);

    holder.render(myData);

    ....
}
```

And finally, the `render` function of my `MyViewHolder` looks like this:

```
public void render(MyData data, boolean expand) {
    mBinding.setData(data); // mBinding is an instance of ListItemMyDataBinding
}
```

And in my `xml`s there are some data bindings:

```
<data>

    <import type="com.example.MyData" />

    <variable
        name="data"
        type="MyData" />
</data>

...

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{data.userName}" />
```

I use this approach in a searchable list, so I have a search field on top of the list. Once a user enters a new search term, list is cleared and notified about change, once the response comes back from server I add all results to the list and notify about the change again.

And finally **the problem** is that the following happens:

- new search term entered: list cleared, items removed [OK]
- response arrives back from server [OK]
- I add all items to the list and notify adapter about the change [OK]
- for a fraction of a second the old values are appearing in the list and list items will be updated with the new values only after that [**NOT OK**]

As I understand, this is because the `View`s are reused and as a first step the adapter realises that it can reuse a view and displays it, and only (a fraction of seconds) after it applies the changes in the layout (through databinding), so that's why I see the old values blinking up. Which is quite annoying.
If in function `render` I manually set a default value to the views (for example `setText("")` on `TextView`s) then I cannot see that blinking effect, but this is not a solution that I want.

Do you have any suggestions how can I nicely avoid this "blinking/lag" effect, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

call

```
mBinding.executePendingBindings ();
```

just after  `mBinding.setData(data);`

Comment: Awesome, thank you :)
I didn't scroll down enough on [the tutorial page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) to see mentioning that function and the importance of it.